# Using Reflection to invoke method with a WebSphere database connection as argument

Tags: java, reflection, websphere, database-connection, datasource

I'm trying the use reflection to invoke a method that has a java.sql.Connection as argument.

```
public void setAndValidateSessionUUID(java.lang.String, java.sql.Connection);
```

I am on a Websphere 7 context using a jndi path to retrieve the data source and it's connection.

```
private java.sql.Connection connection;

Context ctx = new InitialContext();
DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup(this.DataSourceJNDIPath);
this.connection = dataSource.getConnection();
```

I have the following piece of code to retrieve the method using reflection

```
public static Method getMethod(Class<?> clazz, String methodName, Class<?>... args) throws SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException {
    return clazz.getMethod(methodName, args);
}
```

But when I try to retrieve the method it gives me the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: setAndValidateSessionUUID(java.lang.String, com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection)
```

I have no problem executing the method without reflection but using it I can't retrieve the method.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server returns proxy objects, which you can observe via dataSource.getClass().  On WAS 8.0 and later, you can use the java.sql.Wrapper APIs to call vendor-specific APIs, but on WAS 7.0 and later, you'll need to use [WSCallHelper](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/rsadapter/WSCallHelper.html).jdbcCall.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You may want to read my blog post [here](http://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/reflections.html) but basically, you need to iterate all of the classes methods `for (Method method : cls.getMethods())` until you find one where each (and every) method parameter `isAssignableFrom` your input parameters...

```
if (!mTypes[i].isAssignableFrom(parameters[i]
        .getClass()))
```

If it is, store it with `toInvoke = method`. Then use

```
toInvoke.invoke(receiver, parameters);
```